# Будет ли копироваться значение при передаче умных указателей в функцию или будет передаваться ссылка?

Tags: c++, указатели

Например, имеется некоторый класс:

```
class CSomeClass
{
    double GetLengthLine(std::shared_ptr<CPoint> firstVertex, std::shared_ptr<CPoint> secondVertex) const;
}




double CTriangle::GetLengthLine(std::shared_ptr<CPoint> firstVertex, std::shared_ptr<CPoint> secondVertex) const
{
    ....
    return std::hypot(dx, dy);
};
```

Будет ли копироваться значение при передаче умных указателей в функцию, или будет передаваться ссылка?

Comment: Будет либо копироваться либо перемещаться объект shared_ptr в зависимости от того, как будут поставляться аргументы. shared_ptr имеет как копирующий конструктор, так и перемещающий конструктор. Ваши функции объявляют соответствующий параметр по значению, а не как ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос (хотя на этот счет есть сомнение, т.к. уже имеется принятый ответ), то речь всё же о копировании объекта типа `CPoint`, которым параметризован `std::shared_ptr`. В этом случае совершенно не важно как будет передаваться объект умного указателя по ссылке или по значению - это не приведет к дополнительному копированию объекта, хранимого в указателе. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    S(const S&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    S(S&&) { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};

void f(std::shared_ptr<S>) {}
void g(const std::shared_ptr<S>&) {}

int main(){

    auto s = std::make_shared<S>();
    f(s);
    g(s);
}
```

[Вывод:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6MgppgclP6eD9c57)

> ctor

Т.е. был создан только один объект. Ни копирований, ни перемещений не произошло. Это в принципе логично, т.к. подобным же образом не происходит создания (полезных) объектов при передаче обычных (не умных) указателей.

В общем случае, любой достаточно большой (более нескольких `sizeof(int)`) объект имеет смысл передавать по константной ссылке, если не предполагается его модифицировать.

Answer (score 4):

Так как параметры ваших функций принимают объект типа `std::shared_ptr<CPoint>` по значению, то в функции будут передаваться копии аргументов, с которыми они вызваны.  То есть соответствующий аргумент либо будет перемещаться, либо копироваться в параметр функции, так как класс `std::shared_ptr` имеет как конструктор копирования, так и конструктор перемещения.

Но будет меняться число ссылок на тот указатель, который обернут в `std::shared_ptr`. То есть при вызове функций будет меняться счетчик ссылок на исходный "сырой" указатель.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void f( std::shared_ptr<int> p )
{ 
    std::cout << "Inside f() shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = " 
              << p.use_count()
              << std::endl;
}             

int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p( new int ( 10 ) );

    std::cout << "Before calling f shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = "
              << p.use_count()
              << std::endl;

    f( p );

    std::cout << "Aftera calling f shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = "
              << p.use_count()
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий

```
Before calling f shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = 1
Inside f() shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = 2
After calling f shared_ptr<int>::use_count() = 1
```